# Autolayout error in list of images using tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I want to display list of remote images in a table view programatically that fits screen width.

My table view has this constraint: `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

I create a cell, add an image and create constrains.

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
let url = URL(string: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/411089/pexels-photo-411089.jpeg")
let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
let imageView = UIImageView()
cell.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data!)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
return cell
```

And I get this (section Photos):

[image: Photos section - distorted]

The image render is incorrect, the height too big. I tried to fix it and added a ratio constraint:

```
let ratio = imageView.image!.size.height/imageView.image!.size.width
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio).isActive = true
```

And after that, the images display correct, but I get a non-fatal error about constrains:
[image: good layout, but with constraint warning]

Error for each image:

```
2017-09-10 23:50:52.490946+0300 MyHelloWorld[35126:1135489] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009eaa0 UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.height == 0.667391*UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ec30 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ecd0 UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.trailing == UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ed20 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009edc0 UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.bottom == UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009efa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00.height == 213.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009eeb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCell:0x7fe4608a0c00.width == 320   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009eaa0 UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.height == 0.667391*UIImageView:0x7fe4605236e0.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I don't know what exactly this constraint-exception means. And I don't know how to fix it. Help, please, I already spent a few days for this exception.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the constraint's priority from 1000 to 999. That way, the encapsulated layout dimensions of the table view cell can be applied firstly.

```
let imageRatioConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio)
imageRatioConstraint.priority = 999
imageRatioConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes, fixed! Thank you so much!